# Passing python variable to another script

Tags: python, variables

I am pretty new to programming with python. So apologies in advance:
I have two python scripts which should share variables. Furthermore the first script (first.py) should call second script (second.py)

first.py:

```
import commands
x=5
print x
cmd = "path-to-second/second.py"
ou = commands.getoutput(cmd)
print x
```

second.py looks like this

```
print x
x=10
print x
```

I would expect the output:
5
5
10
10

In principle I need a way to communicate between the two scripts. Any solution which does this job is perfectly fine.

Thank you for your help!

Tim

Comment: I want to extend my question. (I am not sure if that is the right way to do it, so again apologies in advance.)
Thank you for you help! - Like this I am able to use the variables of first.py in second.py
Is there an easy way to use the variables of second.py in first.py after second.py has finished running?
I can think of writing variables/values in a separate file and reading that in. Is there another more direct way?
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Each python script has its own root scope, and in this case you're launching another entirely separate process, so its `x` is completely different from the other script's `x`, otherwise each python script would have to have unique variable names to avoid collision.

What you probably want to do is provide the values needed by `second.py` on the command line. Here's a simple way to do that:

first.py:

```
import commands
x=5
print x
cmd = "path-to-second/second.py " + str(x)
ou = commands.getoutput(cmd)
```

second.py:

```
import sys
x = int(sys.argv[1]) # sys.argv[0] is "second.py"
print x
x=10
print x
```

Answer (score 1):

In your second.py, you'll want these lines

```
from sys import argv
x = argv[1]   #Second argument (starts at 0, which is the script name)
```

Then your first.py should execute second.py such as

```
import os
os.system("python second.py " + x)
```